# ComboboxItem Expanding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

This seems like it should be pretty easy to find/implement, but I've had no luck.

I need a simple combobox in which one of the items expands to the right when the mouse hovers over it for more options. I tried adding a second combobox as the child of the first, but I can't get it to open to the right using .

I'm not married to the child combobox and will take any good suggestion.

The code beneath gives me an error: 'Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemsSource' threw an exception.' Line number '154' and line position '123', where line 154 is

```
<ComboBoxItem Tag="163" Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">£ - Pound</ComboBoxItem>
```

This is the code:

```
<ComboBox Name="SettingsCmbx" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0"  Width="80" Style="{StaticResource blackGradientComboBox}" Margin="3">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="Options" IsEnabled="False" Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}" FontSize="12" Foreground="White">Options</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">Guidelines</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">Copy Investigation</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBox Name="CurrencySelectCmbx" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0" Width="80" Style="{StaticResource blackGradientComboBox}">
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" Placement="Right"></Popup>
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <ComboBoxItem Tag="36" Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">Currency</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Tag="36" Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">$ - Dollar</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Tag="163" Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">£ - Pound</ComboBoxItem>
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            </ComboBox>
```

To give an idea of how the backend is implemented (incomplete):

```
Private Sub SettingsCmbx_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles SettingsCmbx.SelectionChanged
    Dim selection As String = SettingsCmbx.SelectedItem.content.ToString()
    If selection = "Options" Then Return

    If selection = "Guidelines" Then
        Dim answer As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Navigate to NDIA website to view 32 Guidelines?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)
        If answer = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            Process.Start("http://www.ndia.org/Divisions/Divisions/Procurement/PMSC/Pages/PMSCCommitteeDocuments.aspx")
        End If
    ElseIf selection = "About" Then
        Dim helpwindow As New HelpWindow
        helpwindow.Show()
    ElseIf selection = "Copy Investigation" Then
        Dim _investigationcopymappingwindow As New InvestigationCopyMappingWindow
        _investigationcopymappingwindow.Show()
    ElseIf selection = "Currency" Then
        'WHERE THE CHILD SELECTION CODE SHOULD THEORETICALLY GO
    End If

    SettingsCmbx.SelectedIndex() = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I would search for a MenuItem , with a Combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Menu system inside your ComboBox:

```
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Height="25">
                <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem1" Header="Testing" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" MouseEnter="MenuItem_MouseEnter">
                <MenuItem Header="IfThisWorks" Background="White" BorderThickness="0"/>
            </MenuItem>
```

Using this to open the menu when mouse over:

```
    private void MenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem1.IsSubmenuOpen = true;
    }
```

Comment: This worked, however I can't for the life of me get the menuitem to fill the space that the combobox provides it. There's these two white spaces to the right and left of it that make it look like it's too small. Suggestions?